# Displaying info of users from FB and Gmail Login

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully performed FB login and Gmail using SDKs and pods. Now, I want to print the users info of name from FB and Gmail. I have searched but couldn't find the possible solutions in Swift3. It doesn't display the name from FB login and Gmail login. It shows error as

Comment: are you updated url section for FB & G+ ,also are you implement     func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool  method in appDelegate

Comment: Yes I have update @ Hosny

Comment: still get same error ? @Tamannah

Comment: Yes the same error m getting  @  Hosny

Comment: try to call current access token before  fetchProfile try this code       
        if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken(){
            fetchProfile()

        }

Comment: I tried it... It couldn't solve. It shows an error     Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = Fkq1zE4LlfO;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
},

Comment: com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0})  @ Honsy

Comment: Its a one long error. Since stack overflow doesn't allow me to posts screenshot so i posted on 2 comments . Please have a look and help me to find solution @ Honsy

Comment: ok , is your app on Facebook developer live and has green circle ?

Comment: No, Its on development mode @ Hosny

Comment: ok, try to make it public , so go to your app -> app review -> and click make <your app name> public and try again

Comment: Again same error ... @ Hosny

Comment: so , i faced this error before when using fb login and i fixed it with those suggests , can you show your app delegate and info plist  ?

Comment: update you question with your secreenshots for your question be helpful

Comment: ok ,you can add your image as link , BTW this is my email elsayed.hussein15@gmail.com

Comment: yes i received your meal and i send you response can you check your mail ? and tell me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you implement deprecated method that called after you mad authentication  in appDelegate you must implement following method

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
if url.scheme?.contains("fb"){
  let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, 
                      open: url, 
                      sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?, 
                      annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled
}
else {
          return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                                        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
}
```

and also to get data for gmail login you must conform following delegate 
`GIDSignInDelegate` and add this line

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

Comment: @ Hosny Thank you Sir :) Perfect answer. You made my day